# Instantiating module in condiotional block verilog

Tags: verilog, if, module

Considering a module cannot be instantiated inside `if` block, how are we supposed to instantiate the module outside the `if-else` block, keeping in mind that the inputs given to module in `if` and `else` blocks are different?

Problem:

```
if(sel==0)
  moduleex s1(inp1,out);
else
  moduleex s2(inp2,out);
```

What is the legal way to write this logic in proper Verilog syntax?

Comment: you should consider updating your verilog code to be correct syntax (you probably meant `if (sel==0)` ) and add the always block to make clear.  Without any context, this could also be interpreted as a `generate` block

Comment: Just from a terminology standpoint, it's not an ```if``` **block** - it's a statement. The bit that it is in (e.g. ```initial```, ```always```, ```generate```, etc.) is the block. You can't conditionally instantiate modules within procedural blocks (```always```, ```initial```), but you can in ```generate``` blocks. However that only works with parameters, not variables. Remember, you are describing hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy — put the multiplexer outside the module:

```
assign inp = sel ? inp2 : inp1;
moduleex s1 (inp, out);
```

You can even do it all in one line if you're so inclined, but this tends to be less readable:

```
moduleex s1 (sel ? inp2 : inp1, out);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A#Verilog):

```
wire out_s1;
wire out_s2;
wire out;

moduleex s1(
    .in(inp1),
    .out(out_s1));

moduleex s2(
    .in(inp2),
    .out(out_s2));

assign out = (sel == 0) ? out_s1 : out_s2;
```

The last line means IF sel IS 0 THEN use out_s1 ELSE use out_s2.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a sec... the question is asking about conditional *instantiation* of two different instances of moduleex: s1 or s2. Conditional instantiation is a compile-time option, not a procedural like ‘if’. Conditional instantiation is something you do with `ifdef or genvar - only once, when the logic is compiled.

Unfortunately, hardware being what it is, to model what is being asked - selecting between one instance and another - you have no choice but to create *both* instance s1 and s2 before the ‘if’ statement, then modify the ‘if’ to select the output of one instance or the other. That’s shown above, but I wanted to make clear that’s the reason why.

Now, having done that, if for some reason the variable *sel* never changes (e.g, with an *assign*) then synthesis might prune away the unused moduleex instance. But nevertheless both instances of moduleex still need to be declared before the selecting ‘if’, they can’t be declared in it.

The answer that shows modifying the variables to one instance - while correct - misses the point.